# Plone ZODB Database records in the future

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

I have a problem with a plone-instance. On startup i get this CRITICAL Message

> 2011-03-25 10:23:06 CRITICAL ZODB.FileStorage /srv/plone/var/filestorage/Data.fs Database records 1258954454 seconds in the future

In the ZMI i can see that the plone - instance folder and everything in it has the date "2051-02-14 15:57" (it is the value of bobobase_modification_time). Every new object has the very same timestamp.

Due to that the packing of the ZODB doesn't make the Data.fs smaller and starting of the instance takes a long time right before the CRITICAL message above appears. Other than that, the site seems to work okay. Especially within Plone the time values seem to be correct.

I checked to following (syntax-higlighted version of debug-session here: http://pastie.org/1709881):

> >>> plone = app.plonesite
>   >>> plone.created()
>   DateTime('2010/11/15 13:39:42.694 GMT+1')
>   >>> plone.modified()
>   DateTime('2010/11/15 13:39:42.694 GMT+1')
>   >>> plone.bobobase_modification_time()
>   DateTime('2051/02/14 15:57:21.077 GMT+1')
>
> # Try to set creation date according to
>   # http: //plone.org/documentation/kb/set-creation-date
>   # setCreationDate doesn't work anymore
>
> >>> from DateTime import DateTime
>   >>> d = DateTime('2010/11/16')
>   >>> plone.setModificationDate(d)
>   >>> plone.setCreationDate(d)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in ?
>   AttributeError: setCreationDate
>   >>> plone.setEffectiveDate(d)
>   >>> plone.reindexObject()
>
> >>> plone.created()
>   DateTime('2010/11/15 13:39:42.694 GMT+1')
>   >>> plone.modified()
>   DateTime('2010/11/16')
>   >>> plone.bobobase_modification_time()
>   DateTime('2051/02/14 15:57:21.077 GMT+1')

What can I do about the wrong time of the bobobase_modification_time()? Can I set this value somhow to a reasonable time?

Update: Writing this post brought to me some new ideas what to search for. I think the thread http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.zope.general/12994/focus=12999 describes what happend with my site. I will now try to fix it with exporting an then importing the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran Zope on a server with the clock way off into the future, and the ZODB really doesn't like that.

Someone once wrote a patch to auto-correct for this situation, see:

http://www.mail-archive.com/zodb-dev@zope.org/msg03916.html

YMMV applying that one though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This sounds very promising. Unfortunatly I haven't figured out yet, how to apply the solution. Simply patching BaseStorage.py doesn't seem to be it. If I am missing something obvious, i would be glad to get advice. Otherwise I'll try a bit more.